# Python: using a function that returns two items in an If statement, without executing twice

Tags: python, function, if-statement

I have a function I'm using to test in an if/then.

The issue is that I'm executing the function BOTH in the if conditional, and then again after the if statement because the function returns two items.

This just seems wasteful and I'm trying to think of ways to improve this. Here's a really basic version of what I'm trying to avoid: "True" is returned to allow the condition to pass, but then then "coolstuff()" is executed again to get more information from the function.

"coolstuff()" *could* possibly return false, so I can't use the returned string "stuff" as the test.

```
def coolstuff():
    return True, "stuff"
    
if coolstuff()[0]:
    coolthing = coolstuff()[1]
    print coolthing
```

There's gotta be a better way to do this, no? My brain is melting a little as I try to hash it out.

I basically want to do something like this (invalid) syntax:

```
def coolstuff():
    return True, "stuff"
    
if a, b == coolstuff() and a:
    print b
```

Comment: `val = coolstuff(); if val[0]:`

Comment: Could you just return None if the coolstuff() output is invalid and check to see if your return is None?

Answer (score 2):

Just collect both results into variables

```py
a, b = fn()
if a:
    # work with b
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def coolstuff():
    if valid:
        return "stuff"
    return None

data = coolstuff()
if data:
    print(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Call the function and capture the *entire* returned value:

```
x = coolstuff()
```

Now you have access to both parts of the returned value, in `x[0]` and `x[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

Store it:

```
state, coolvar = coolstuff()
if state:
   do_whatever(coolvar)
```

Answer (score 0):

If in newer Python, you could use the dreaded walrus (but I prefer ti7's approach of just assigning in a separate line):

```
if (x := coolstuff())[0]:
    print(x[1])
```